# Object reference error sending an object to UserControl method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm close to getting the core functionality  ready for a practise project I've been working on, but not surprisingly I've gotten stuck on something and could use some help or pointers.

Basically, I'm sending an object to a User control, who sends it to another user control where an image is chosen by useing the contents of the object, then from the first user control I add the second user control to the first user control. Or atleast I would, if I didn't get errors about an object reference being required. It's the **HandGUI.CreateCard(newCard);** line in Form1 that gives an object reference error. If I make CreateCard static it works, but then I can't use the this keyword to place the controls in User Control1.

In Form1:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Card newCard = TheDeck.Draw();

        HandGUI.CreateCard(newCard);
    }
```

In User Control1:

```
public void CreateCard(Card card)
    {
        CardGUI cardGui = new CardGUI(card);

        cardGui.Size = new Size(71, 96);
        cardGui.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        cardGui.Show();

        this.Controls.Add(cardGui);
    }
```

In User Control2:

```
    public CardGUI(CardGameLibrary.Card newCard)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeGUI();

        AssignImage(newCard);
    }

    private void AssignImage(Card card)
    {
        string faceVal = card.FaceVal.ToString();
        string suit = card.Suit.ToString();
        string fullName;

        if (faceVal == "Ace")
            faceVal = "1";
        if (faceVal == "Two")
            faceVal = "2";
        if (faceVal == "Three")
            faceVal = "3";
        if (faceVal == "Four")
            faceVal = "4";
        if (faceVal == "Five")
            faceVal = "5";
        if (faceVal == "Six")
            faceVal = "6";
        if (faceVal == "Seven")
            faceVal = "7";
        if (faceVal == "Eight")
            faceVal = "8";
        if (faceVal == "Nine")
            faceVal = "9";
        if (faceVal == "Ten")
            faceVal = "10";
        if (faceVal == "Jack")
            faceVal = "j";
        if (faceVal == "Queen")
            faceVal = "q";
        if (faceVal == "King")
            faceVal = "k";

        fullName = suit + faceVal;

            if(cardList.Images[fullName] != null)
            {
                PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
                picBox.Image = cardList.Images[fullName];
                picBox.Size = new Size(71, 96);
                this.Controls.Add(picBox);
            }
    }
```

Creating a form in User Control2 at the end and adding the picturebox to that form shows that it's working that far atleast in regards to finding the right picture. Hope someone has some idea about what I can do, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but an enum might be easier to handle for the face value if statement you have set up.

Comment: You need to new up an instance of HandGUI like you did with CardGUI before you can call CreateCard() on it.

Comment: I'll have to add that I'm a beginner, and I can't debug when I don't understand what's wrong. Visual Studio says an Object Reference is Required for non-static yada yada. But I don't know what this means, and if I make that target method static it works, but then I can't use the this keyword to add controls.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar, you should check out some of the debugging tools visual studio offers. I found a tutorial that might help out, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Chu, that set me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the class HandGUI, rather than an instance. If you're not initializing a HandGUI object, you'd see a null reference exception with the function call. If you set the function to static, you'd no longer have an error since static implies the function can be called without initializing the class it's contained in.

```
HandGUI newHandGUI = new HandGUI();
newHandGUI.CreateCard(newCard);
```